# How to retain layout when webview follows links

Tags: android

I have a layout where there are buttons at the top and bottom of a screen with a large webview in the center between the buttons. When a link in webview is clicked, the webview becomes full-screen, but I want to keep the buttons and retain the original layout. How can this be done?

My webview is simple and looks like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);    

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://ya-dee-ya");
    ;
    ;
    }
```

Comment: You mean you want to see this top and bottom button also while the url is loaded ?? right ??

Comment: I face the same issue, But iDroid's answer solve my problem. Thanks to iDroid.

Answer (score 1):

Set webview client and use shouldOverrideUrlLoading

```
  myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }


    });
```

Comment: +1 Yes totally agree with this answer, @Rich you can implement WebViewClient to handle URL opening in the same screen

Comment: except... after this change, the 'setJavaScriptEnabled(true)' (as previously implemented) no longer seems to work. Any ideas?? TIA

Answer (score 0):

In My Point of view, You have to do Something with that XML file. . 
Just set the top and bottom margin of the Webview according to the height of that buttons. it will show the Buttons while you are loading the webview. . .